# Disable focusing of PageControl's tab header

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Delphi 7, TPageControl with tabs. If I click tab header, it becomes focused (dotted frame is painted). It's not needed here, I want to always keep focus of tab contents (inside pagecontrol). How to disable focus on tab headers?

E.g. Notepad++ disables it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set [`TabStop`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TPageControl.TabStop) of your [`TPageControl`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TPageControl) to False.